# What is taking up my disk space?

Tags: hard-disk, disk-usage

```
root@ubuntu:/home/user8# df -h

Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        3.2G  218M  3.0G   7% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  3.6T  186G  3.2T   6% /
tmpfs                         16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                         16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                    473M  248M  202M  56% /boot
/dev/sda1                    511M  3.4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                        3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1001
```

I see 186G used on my Ubuntu machine, but when I try to find where these are, I get:

```
root@ubuntu:/# ncdu
    3.2 GiB [##########] /home
    1.7 GiB [#####     ] /usr
    1.3 GiB [###       ] /var
    1.1 GiB [###       ] /lib
  248.2 MiB [          ] /boot
  217.0 MiB [          ] /run
   35.3 MiB [          ] /tmp
   21.1 MiB [          ] /opt
   16.2 MiB [          ] /bin
   13.3 MiB [          ] /sbin
    7.4 MiB [          ] /root
    7.2 MiB [          ] /etc
e  16.0 KiB [          ] /lost+found
    8.0 KiB [          ] /media
    8.0 KiB [          ] /snap
    4.0 KiB [          ] /lib64
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /srv
e   4.0 KiB [          ] /mnt
.   0.0   B [          ] /proc
    0.0   B [          ] /sys
    0.0   B [          ] /dev
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  initrd.img
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz.old
@   0.0   B [          ]  vmlinuz
```

And:

```
root@ubuntu:/# du -sh /*
17M     /bin
249M    /boot
0       /dev
7.3M    /etc
3.3G    /home
0       /initrd.img
0       /initrd.img.old
1.2G    /lib
4.0K    /lib64
16K     /lost+found
8.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
22M     /opt
du: cannot access '/proc/15646/task/15646/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/15646/task/15646/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/15646/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access '/proc/15646/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
0       /proc
7.4M    /root
218M    /run
14M     /sbin
8.0K    /snap
4.0K    /srv
0       /sys
36M     /tmp
1.8G    /usr
1.4G    /var
0       /vmlinuz
0       /vmlinuz.old
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: You should use the command `sudo du -sh /*` instead the ncdu tool. You could see /var directory is using space

Comment: root@ubuntu:/# du -sh /*
17M     /bin
249M    /boot
0       /dev
7.3M    /etc
3.3G    /home
0       /initrd.img
0       /initrd.img.old
1.2G    /lib
4.0K    /lib64
16K     /lost+found
8.0K    /media
4.0K    /mnt
22M     /opt
0       /proc
7.4M    /root
218M    /run
14M     /sbin
8.0K    /snap
4.0K    /srv
0       /sys
36M     /tmp
1.8G    /usr
1.4G    /var

Comment: Of course, we already have https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3961/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5156/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13828/ , 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/208953/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/414417/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232493/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125429/, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406526/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285665/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13828/ .

Answer (score 0):

Well, its clear this 186G after kill some process who i use. In my case ( SCREEN )
Or need to reboot and all is ok. I will try to optimize the scripts and avoid this problem. Tnk

> JdeBP

for list of answer :)